# How can I create a layout in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, page-layout, layout

How can I make a design like the example below.  When I generate some lorem ipsum text, I don't know how to set up columns, or how to set the text to wrap around the letter.

[image]

Comment: What part? What have you tried? Where are you struggling? What *exactly* is the "font problem"?

Comment: I don t now when I generate lorem ipsum how I can set rows and colums  like on image and also how to set text wrap around the letter

Comment: While you can use illustrator why arent you using indesign?

Comment: This is school project and must be in illustrator

Comment: There's no column functionality within text boxes in Illustrator. You'll need to make individual text boxes for each column. Text wrap is under *Object > Text Wrap > Make*.

Comment: If this is a school project, haven't they taught you anything about Illustrator if they mandate you use Illustrator?

Comment: @BillyKerr My AI has a column option for area type.... draw an area type box then `Type > Area Type Options..` Am I special? I didn't think I was `:)`

Comment: If I ever become a teacher I'm going to have all students make a 300 page manual in Photoshop CS 3. This is the type of stuff my dreams are made of... "What's that, George?" George: "...Does CS 3 at least have artboards?" Me: "HAHA HA HAAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaa. No. Now run along you... *muffled laugher continues through the classroom door * _haaaaaahaaaaaa hue hue hue hue hue -aaaah... hhihaaa!_"

Comment: @Scott - No you're right. It's a feature I didn't realise was there. I stand corrected.

Comment: See I just *knew* I wasn't special.. my mom such is a liar!!! 

Comment: @Scott - I must remember to write "as far as I know" after everything I comment on;)

Comment: @BillyKerr, I think you should, as far as I know...

Comment: @Joonas - the thing is, I usually do, as far as I know. LOL

Comment: As far as I know, you don't. But, as far as I know, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, we now appear to have an answer. So here it is:

1. Make a text box
2. Do *Type > Area Type Options* and set the number of columns, gutter, span, etc.
3. Place an object over the text
4. With the object selected, do *Object > Text Wrap > Make*

Comment: To be totaly honest your now robbing OP of the benefits of doing 15 minutes of discovery in the software. Whi h honestly is a life skill.